# Is it normal to have really slow text transfer in Sublime Text 2 with the Clojure REPL?

Tags: clojure, sublimetext2, sublimerepl

Text transfer is really slow for me in Sublime Text 2, especially multiline text (each line takes about 2 seconds to print in the repl before evaluating the whole expression...)
Is it normal?

It would be better if I could remove line endings before sending expressions to the repl, so in my command, I've added a step:

```
text = text.rstrip()
```

but it doesn't work.

How can I make this faster?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change the SublimeREPL clojure command from `lein repl` to `lein trampoline run -m clojure.main`. Everything should be nice and fast after that.

The file you want to change is `SublimeREPL/config/Clojure/Main.sublime-menu`