# Sublime Text 3 Python REPL Slow print

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I have pretty much the identical problem to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835788/is-it-normal-to-have-really-slow-text-transfer-in-sublime-text-2-with-the-clojur) but with python. Printing large amounts of text will even crash my sublime text. Unfortunately the solution described is specific to Clojure. Any ideas?

Clarification: I encounter the slow down if the code prints stuff too fast without a delay. This code will do it:

```
for x in range(1000000):
    print(x)
```

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. What exactly are you doing when Sublime slows down? Are you transferring code from another window to the REPL? Are you running code in the REPL, and it's just taking a long time to print? How much data are we talking about here? Please [edit] your question and add as much detail as possible. Some sample code that illustrates the problem would also be extremely helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I don't think I've ever experienced this to the effect that Sublime crashed. It'll slow down a bit as everything is printing out, and perhaps pause for a second or so, but never crash. I've seen it the same way - accidentally printing out an entire pandas dataframe, for example. Do you just have an abnormally under-powered system with not much RAM?

Comment: I'm running it on a system which should handle this. Running the same programs in Terminal doesn't doesn't cause a slowdown

Comment: I'm also having the same issue. I'm writing a scraper when I try to print the response.text from requests my sublime is not responding for a few seconds. This only happens when I use SublimeREPL